# Parsing from string to date

Tags: java, date

I am a little lost here , I think i do everything ok and it still does not work (PaseException

```
    String time = "Fri Apr 15 14:29:57 IDT 2011";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    sdf.parse(time);
```

Help highly appreciated!

Comment: Both Jigar and myself and John have given the correct answer however, it would be helpful to anyone reading this in the future to know what your default Locale is. Please can you edit the question to give your default locale.One line of code will return your default locale :: System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().toString());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String time = "Fri Apr 15 14:29:57 IDT 2011";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(time));
```

Works fine for me.!

May be you can try with

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your default locale is not compatible with this date pattern.

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

(I confirmed this as working)

Answer (score 1):

add locale as second constructor parameter:

```
    String time = "Fri Apr 15 14:29:57 IDT 2011";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(sdf.parse(time));
```